# Create object on demand

Tags: javascript

i have a rather unusual question. 
We have a web-based system, which is free programmable for our customers. This means that our customer can control and fetch data through script. Today we use a basic-interpreter, and we would like to switch to JavaScript.

the exposed objects has tens of thousands propertys, and its to slow to create all of them when launching the web-application. Therefore, i would like to find out if there is a way of doing it on demand. An example:

```
var reallyLargeObject = {}; //root object, with many many propertys(the propertys has subpropertys in a tree as well.
```

This object is created out of control of our customer. but, in the customer scripts there will be code like:

```
    reallyLargeObject.subProperty.subsubProperty = 23;
```

of course this will result in an "object is not defined", But i want to catch this somehow (through some override of some prototype function maybe?) and create the property on demand like:

```
function(subpropertyName){
    reallyLargeObject[subpropertyName]=createSubProperty(subpropertyName);
}
```

before returning to .subsubProperty call... Is this even possible?

Thank's in advance :)
/Teo

Comment: It is possible to a degree to monkey patch JavaScript methods but that's a code smell and should not be done. Your problem is solved by rethinking the front end architecture and not by hacking on JavaScript.

Comment: By 'basic-interpreter' you mean the BASIC programming language?

Comment: It's simpler to go with setter function like `namespace(reallyLargeObject, 'subProperty.subsubProperty', 23);` which would create necessary structure and set value.

Comment: @JevZelenkov i mean an self-implemented BASIC interpreter that gives callbacks when a undefined value is evaluated. there are thousands of existing configurations, with these scripts involved, that we want to migrate to a new platform. The customers is used to the scripting architecture, therefore the object is RootObject.[~6000 propertys].[20-1000 subpropertys].[~20 valuepropertys]... there can be up to 1000 root objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible provided the JavaScript engine has ES5 features (all modern browsers do, older browsers like IE8 don't). You still have to add the top-level properties in advance, but you don't have to initialize them. ES6 will make it possible to truly lazy-init the properties.

#### ES5 - `defineProperty` / `defineProperties`

You'd do it by implementing a lazy-initialization property getter using `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.defineProperties`.

You have two choices for lazy-init: Redefine the property on first use, or use a backing variable.

Here's an example using redefinition; this has the advantage that once the init is done, you don't have getters/setters anymore, just a boring old property:

```js
// REUSABLE utility function: Make a redefinable property
function makeLazyInitProp(o, name, builder) {
  Object.defineProperty(o, name, {
    // Getter
    get: function() {
      snippet.log("Getter for " + name + " called, redefining");
      var value = builder(this);
      Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
        value: value,
        writable: true
      });
      return value;
    },
    
    // Setter, if you want one
    set: function(value) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
        value: value,
        writable: true
      });
    },

    // Has to be configurable
    configurable: true
  });
}

// Make our object with `foo` and `bar` properties
var obj = {};
makeLazyInitProp(obj, "foo", function() {
  return {
    message: "This is the foo property's message"
  };
});
makeLazyInitProp(obj, "bar", function() {
  return {
    message: "This is the bar property's message"
  };
});

// Use it, note we only see the "Getter for X called,
// redefining" message *once* for each property
// foo
snippet.log(obj.foo.message);
snippet.log(obj.foo.message);
// bar
snippet.log(obj.bar.message);
snippet.log(obj.bar.message);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Using a backing value instead:

```js
// REUSABLE utility function: Make a property using a backing value
function makeLazyProp(o, name, builder) {
  var pending = true, value;
  Object.defineProperty(o, name, {
    // Getter
    get: function() {
      if (pending) {
        snippet.log("Building " + name + " property");
        value = builder(this);
        pending = false;
      }
      return value;
    },
    
    // Setter, if you want one
    set: function(v) {
      value = v;
      pending = false;
    }
  });
}

// Make our object with `foo` and `bar` properties
var obj = {};
makeLazyProp(obj, "foo", function() {
  return {
    message: "This is the foo property's message"
  };
});
makeLazyProp(obj, "bar", function() {
  return {
    message: "This is the bar property's message"
  };
});

// Use it, note we only see the "Building X property"
// message *once* for each property
// foo
snippet.log(obj.foo.message);
snippet.log(obj.foo.message);
// bar
snippet.log(obj.bar.message);
snippet.log(obj.bar.message);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

#### ES6 - `Proxy`

ES6 will have *proxies*, which are pretty much what they sound like: Objects that are really facades on top of (proxies for) other objects. Proxies can get involved in virtually all things you can do with the object they're wrapped around — including getting and setting properties.

Firefox's SpiderMonkey engine has proxies right now, so you can use the below in Firefox (but not most other browsers):

```js
// Create the object
var obj = (function() {
  // This is the *real* object we'll return a proxy for
  var real = {};

  // These are the functions that will lazy-init our properties
  var builders = {
    foo: function(o) {
      snippet.log("Building foo property");
      o.foo = {
        message: "This is foo's message"
      };
    },
    bar: function(o) {
      snippet.log("Building bar property");
      o.bar = {
        message: "This is bar's message"
      }
    }
  };

  // Create our proxy for `real`
  var p = new Proxy(real, {
    // `get` is called whenever the proxy is asked for a
    // property, and passed the underlying object and the
    // property name
    get: function(o, name) {
      // If we have a build and the underlying object doesn't
      // yet have the property, build it
      if (builders[name] && !o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        builders[name](o);
      }

      // Return the (possibly-newly-built) property value
      return o[name];
    }
  });

  // Return the proxy (facade)
  return p;
})();

// Use it, note we only see the "Building X property"
// message *once* for each property
// foo
snippet.log(obj.foo.message);
snippet.log(obj.foo.message);
// bar
snippet.log(obj.bar.message);
snippet.log(obj.bar.message);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so fast!
Ok, nice, but still a question, if foo is a property among the 5000 other propertys under obj, it means that i have to define them anyway (even if they never will be used).. i understand that i can initialize each subproperty with its subpropertys this way, but i was searching for something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod or something else that is a standard feature of the language.
In worst case, this provided solution is enough!

Comment: @TeodorAndersson: Not in ES5. You'll be able to in ES6, I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want. Need to wait for es6-compatible browsers then... Thank you for providing a complete answer!